# Game Company Tag too non-specific?

Tags: feature-request

So I saw a question today about Starbase Jeff (a great game) from Cheapass Games. The game is tagged Starbase Jeff however it's very unlikely to generate more questions since the rules are simple and well written, and therefore unlikely to generate questions... However there are plenty of other Cheapass Games out there... Might it be worth making a Cheapass-Games tag?

Comment: Why? What would be the benefit of an umbrella tag for games by this company? For example, are they all mechanically similar, so that questions about one are likely to be relevant to the others?

Comment: I just did a quick check of the tag pages and I didn't look at every single one, but it looks like we have 200+ tags with only a single question. So this  is not a thing that we have issues with.

Comment: Related: [Is tag:avalonhill a good tag?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1360/3389)

Answer (score 3):

### Many companies have varied games, and a company-specific tag doesn't make sense

As of this writing, there is one question each for [trivial-pursuit](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivial-pursuit), [trouble-despicable-me](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trouble-despicable-me), and [words-with-friends](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words-with-friends). Should we replace them all with [hasbro](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hasbro) since they are all published by the same company? I don't see the value of that, since they are such different games (to be frank, I'd be surprised to find someone who has *played* all of them).

There is the meta discussion [Is tag:avalonhill a good tag?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1360/3389) where there is the argument that because Avalon Hill creates games that are similar in style that it should exist (frankly, I disagree with that, but that's another matter). Still, nobody in that discussion advocated *replacing* the game tags with [avalon-hill](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avalon-hill). Instead, the question was over whether or not it should be there *in addition to* the game tag.

### There's a fair chance that we would want to add game-specific tags back in in the future

#### Who's to say that there won't be more questions?

Consider the tag [thebes](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thebes). The first question was in April 2013, and someone might have had this same meta discussion about that game then. It wasn't until 3 1/2 years later that we got two more questions for the game. We don't know what sort of questions there will be in the future, so it's quite possible that there will be new questions.

Say for example a new version of Starbase Jeff comes out. A question very well might be "What is different between Starbase Jeff first and second editions?".

#### Even simple games can get lots of questions

> The game is tagged Starbase Jeff however  it's very unlikely to generate more questions since the rules are simple and well written

Consider that as of this writing, we have 10 questions for [jenga](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jenga), 8 questions for [tic-tac-toe](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe), and 4 questions for [connect-four](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-four). These are some of the simplest games I know, and yet there are plenty of questions already. You'd be surprised to find out what questions people can ask.